# Eclipse - web app Tomcat deployment borked

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7, classpath

Any help will be much appreciated. I am running a web application which depends on two other projects in my work space. These two projects further depend on 3 other projects in my workspace. There are no errors with any of the projects within the work space. Running the web app within Tomcat produces the following error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tele/misc/DefaultApplicationModule

Which is a class within the first level of dependent projects. All was working fine up until recently. This is obviously some sort of classpath issue? Any suggestions on how to find this within Eclipse metadata and fix this?

More detail:

Console:

```
*******************************************************************
*** WARNING: Apache MyFaces-2 is running in DEVELOPMENT mode.   ***
***                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^         ***
*** Do NOT deploy to your live server(s) without changing this. ***
*** See Application#getProjectStage() for more information.     ***
*******************************************************************

Feb 13, 2014 1:41:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Feb 13, 2014 1:41:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/CRGen] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 13, 2014 1:41:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class         za.co.huge.processor.CRToolContextListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tele/misc/DefaultApplicationModule
    at za.co.huge.processor.ReportProcessor.<init>(ReportProcessor.java:30)
    at za.co.huge.processor.ReportProcessor.getInstance(ReportProcessor.java:41)
    at     za.co.huge.processor.CRToolContextListener.contextDestroyed(CRToolContextListener.java:22)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5573)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Feb 13, 2014 1:41:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 13, 2014 1:41:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 13, 2014 1:41:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2547 ms
```

All of this originating from my servlet context listener:

```
<!-- CRTool Context listener starts report processing Engine -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>za.co.huge.processor.CRToolContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Which fails when init on Guice modules from the dependant project:

```
/* singleton design pattern - so only one service thread can be running */
private ReportProcessor(final long sleepTime){
    serviceThread = new ServiceThread(sleepTime);
    thread = new Thread(serviceThread);
    thread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new     DefaultApplicationModule());
//      final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new CommissionsModule(), new     DefaultApplicationModule());
//      ci = injector.getInstance(CommissionsImpl.class);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the 'Clean' option for Tomcat in Eclipse? Have you tried restarting Tomcat?

Comment: Yes! Clean and re-run many times.

Comment: Can you please add the full stacktrace to your question? There are a few root causes that come to my mind but it's hard guessing which one might be causing your problem.

Comment: Figure out where Eclipse is deploying the application (double click on the server runtime in the 'servers' view), and check what is deployed there. Probably the library is simply not there. And then it is going to be a quest to find out why not and that will depend a lot on what plugins you have or don't have. I would check the deployment assembly of the project, likely it is wonky.

Comment: @Gimby Agreed! The dependent code isn't being deployed. This is exactly what I am trying to figure out...

Comment: As I said, the answer may be in the deployment assembly. Check the project properties.

Comment: I have a feeling the dependent projects aren't being rolled up into the web application because of Ivy dependency management.

The following links may be relevant:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=184125
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVYDE-227

Answer (score 0):

After you compile your code, you end up with `.class` files for each class in your program. These binary files are the bytecode that Java interprets to execute your program. The `NoClassDefFoundError` indicates that the classloader, which is responsible for dynamically loading classes, cannot find the `.class` file for the class that you're trying to use. It probably indicates that you haven't set the classpath option when executing your code. This link explains how to set the classpath when you execute.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29

Comment: My other applications with dependencies run fine! It's just this web-app that has stopped working. It might have happened when I cleaned out my part of my work space and downloaded projects from GIT again.

Comment: ok may be this can help you then https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html

Comment: My Tomcat is working fine... I can create a new web app with no dependencies and run from within Eclipse. I can build a .war and deploy that on Tomcat as well. It's specifically Eclipse and the linking of dependencies that seems to be causing the issue.